# SimpleHttpWorkerRequest with post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently using SimlpeHttpWorkerRequest object to make request to a .net Mvc application for testing purposes.

Based on this blog post http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/06/25/hosting-an-entire-asp-net-mvc-request-for-testing-purposes/

From what I can decipher SimpleHttpWorkerRequest only uses GET requests. How can I use this approach and extend it to other http verbs ?